# Clojurescript: Calling S3 From Browser

Tags: amazon-s3, clojurescript

I am trying to use the AWS SDK to access my S3 bucket and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

My Leiningen project file includes a dependency on the necessary CLJSJS package:

```
[cljsjs/aws-sdk-js "2.94.0-0"]
```

I then require the package in my namespace:

```
(ns my-ns.s3
  (:require [cljsjs.aws-sdk-js]))
```

I set the credentials:

```
(js/AWS.config.update #js{:credentials {:accessKeyId "..."
                                        :secretAccessKey "..."}})
```

I then run this in the REPL using CIDER (I am actually evaluating all of this in CIDER using either `C-M-x` or `C-c C-e`; haven't wired it into any yet):

```
(let [client (new js/AWS.S3)]
  (.listObjects client
                #js{"Bucket" "my-bucket"}
                (fn [err resp]
                  (if err
                    (js/console.error "so sad"
                                      (js/JSON.stringify err))
                    (js/console.log "so happy" resp)))))

=> #object[Request [object Object]]
```

All I get back is that `#object` reference (and I don't know what to do with that). Nothing is logged to the console and no network request goes out.

Any pointers on what I am doing wrong here, or docs I may need to review?

*Details I've omitted for brevity:*

- I am pretty early in learning CLJS, have been learning JS for six months at work, and done CLJ at work for the past few years and Java a few years beyond that
- The above code is inside a `re-frame` project, although I've done very little with the rest of the project
- I previously was able to at least [get CORS errors for `.listBuckets`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1939), but now that call is also doing absolutely nothing -- I don't recall changing anything meaningful